# How do I rotate a list of variables in bash so each time the script is run, it chooses the next variable?

Tags: bash

So when my script runs, I need to choose the next variable in line that is after the one that ran on the previous script run.

Here's what I need to have happen

**Script Run #1**

```
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[0]}

OUTPUT: Run1
```

**Script Run #2**

```
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[1]}

OUTPUT: Run2
```

**Script Run #3**

```
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[2]}

OUTPUT: Run3
```

Then when the script runs on the 4th time, it should go back to the first variable and repeat the rotating process.

**Script Run #4**

```
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[0]}

OUTPUT: Run1
```

---

Now before this, I have just been using sort of a bad method of choosing a random variable when the script starts, but I'm trying to do it properly now. Here's how I was doing it before:

**Script Run #1**

```
rndNum = $(( $RANDOM % 3 ))
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[$rndNum]}

OUTPUT: Run3
```

**Script Run #2**

```
rndNum = $(( $RANDOM % 3 ))
var=(Run1 Run2 Run3)
echo ${var[$rndNum]}

OUTPUT: Run1
```

and so on...

Sorry if this is a  bad question, I am very new to bash.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to store the last index used in another file; the script itself maintains no memory of its last execution.

Comment: BTW -- which operating system is this? Can Linux-y tools like `flock` be used for locking, to ensure two copies of your script started at the same time get different numbers and don't stomp on each other?

Comment: You can write a self-modifying script. You can edit your script during it's execution (ex. using `sed -i "$0" ...`), incrementing the index.

Comment: @KamilCuk, ...one *can*, but "should" is an entirely different matter. With multiple copies of `sed -i` running at once, only one will win -- which is to say, you can have 5 concurrent copies, but the counter only updates by one. That kind of also practice also puts noise into version control history, lends itself to data corruption (blocks on disk that are being rewritten are blocks that are more likely to be impacted by a failure), etc.

Comment: @KamilCuk, ..moreover, that kind of suggestion prevents folks from following good security practices like keeping code and data away from each other, and having code be read-only at runtime (having the runtime user only have the minimum permissions necessary to update data).

Comment: @Kamil Cuk Thanks, didn't think of doing that. I'm going with the answer I chose but your method would also work good because I only have 1 instance of my script running. When it runs, it closes if it's already running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The random-number approach isn't a bad method at all -- it's the *only* method you can use without external storage.

Using that external storage *safely*, in a manner that works correctly even if numerous copies of your script are started at the same time, might look like the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

choices=( one two three )
counterFile=$HOME/.myVar
exec {lock_fd}>"$counterFile.lck"   # first: open a lockfile
flock -x "$lock_fd" || exit         # grab a lock *before* reading the data file
if [[ -s $counterFile ]]; then      # if the data file exists and is populated...
  # add one to its content and rotate if over the number of choices.
  counter=$(( ( $(<"$counterFile") + 1 ) % ${#choices[@]} ))
else
  counter=0                         # otherwise initialize at 0
fi
printf '%s\n' "$counter" >"$counterFile"  # update the file while lock still held
exec {lock_fd}>&-                         # then release the lock

chosen=${choices[$counter]}
echo "This run chose $chosen"
```

This works because `flock` ensures that, however many copies of the script are started at the same time, only one will be able to run the code between `flock -x "$lock_fd"` and `exec {lock_fd}>&-` simultaneously.

Comment: That works perfect. Also learned a few new things too. Thanks!